# is there a way to access the pixels of a video?

Tags: android, video, pixel

Having a video file, there is any way to access single pixel values?

I have two cases where I would like to access the pixels:

1. From the video camera
2. From a video file What I need is geting a pixel information for a certain place with something like getPixel(posX, posY) and returning the RGB information

I have an algorithm that detects blobs (homogeneous parts) of an image and I would like to implement it in real time using the android video camera and offline processing analyzing a video file.

Comment: Yes there is, but a more specific answer will probably require more details.

Comment: I have two cases where I would like to access the pixels: 

1. From the video camera 
2. From a video file 

What I need is geting a pixel information for a certain place with something like getPixel(posX, posY) and returning the RGB information

I have an algorithm that detects blobs (homogeneous parts) of an image and I would like to implement it in real time using the android video camera and offline processing analyzing a video file. 

I hope this is enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll need to do some work.

1. [Extract a video frame](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ffmpeg+get+frame#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&source=hp&q=ffmpeg+get+frame+image&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&fp=ef34c9a9ed856910) from the source file with a tool such as [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org).  The result will be a JPEG or other such image file
2. Use an image processing tool, like [Imagemagick](http://imagemagick.org), to [extract the information for a pixel](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=imagmagick+get&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=imagemagick+get+image+info#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&pq=imagemagick%20get%20pixel&xhr=t&q=imagemagick+get+pixel+color&cp=22&qe=aW1hZ2VtYWdpY2sgZ2V0IHBpeGVsIA&qesig=r2FZV2D_ongD_zwA_PWrug&pkc=AFgZ2tkBx_BLwI6IDMJWyJjMy0o6dv0HzIF7sTbTBbkPQnk885YcKMfkF8ZlRX7VTVLz5fv058UhVVqHBoIBS2Mv0atGLrH_IA&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=imagemagick+get+pixel+&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&fp=ef34c9a9ed856910).

Presto!

Comment: thanks for the answer but what I need is for the android platform :)

Comment: @biquillo: these are open source projects which I believe can be compiled and run on Android

Comment: I've tried some time ago to crosscompile Imagemagick my self but no success. I guess I still have to learn much more :)